# Verificar se email foi eberto com imagem embed ou outra forma

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Estou fazendo um envio de notificações por email com phpmailer.
Essas notificações são muito importantes pois são relatórios de firewall e preciso saber quando a pessoa que deverá as receber leia esta mensagem.

Pesquisei e uma das formas que pensei foi utilizar uma imagem desta forma.

```
<img src='http://site.com/minhaimagem.php?id_envio=762'>
```

só que gmail e outros webmails bloqueiam este tipo de uso.
existe uma forma de eu saber utilizando o phpmailer desta forma:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("Disposition-Notification-To: email@site.com");
```

tenho algumas dúvidas:
tem possibilidade de fornecer uma url de confirmação? ou se no caso de não ter. como eu leria este email de retorno e processaria ele para que eu pudesse por uma flag de lido nele?